# Spring MVC navigation path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem when trying to make some simple navigation in spring mvc. I have a navigation controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/secure")
public class NavigationController {

    @RequestMapping("/operation")
    public String processOperationPage() {
        //Some logic goes here
        return "corpus/operation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/configuration")
    public String processConfigurationPage() {
        //Some logic goes here
        return "corpus/configuration";
    }

}
```

and there is my links to reach that controller:

```
<a href="secure/operation.htm">Operation</a>
<a href="secure/configuration.htm">Configuration</a>
```

When the first time the link is clicked everything is OK. In the browser I see the normal path as I am expecting. For e.g: `http://localhost/obia/secure/configuration.htm`. But if I am at this page, and from this page I want to reach operation.htm when I click the operation link the path becomes like this: `http://localhost/obia/secure/secure/operation.htm`.

The `secure` appears two times. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your links are relative.  Adding a slash in front of them will fix it.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. All answers are right. Unfortunately I can accept only one. I have done this: ${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/secure/configuration.htm and now its working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using JSP, use JSTL instead:

```
<c:url value="/secure/operation.htm" />
```

Remember include taglib in JSP file:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

By using JSTL, you can avoid to change the URL once the app is deploy to different context such as `http://host/` and `http://host/myapp`

The first one will generate `http://host/secure/operation.htm` and second one will generate `http://host/myapp/secure/operation.htm` for you.

Answer (score 2):

Change your URL from relative or calculate relative URL dinamically depending on current page. E.g. you can change your URL to host-based:

```
 
       <a href="/obia/secure/operation.htm">Operation</a>
       <a href="/obia/secure/configuration.htm">Configuration</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Responder above has one correct answer in using c:url to generate an absolute URL.  However, there are situations where the JSTL doesn't know the URL base correctly because of a firewall configuration.  In that case, you can use a relative URL, but it has to know where you're starting from.  i.e. on the page obia/secure/operation.htm, the url would be ../secure/configuration.htm, or just configuration.htm.  The dot dot means to traverse up one level.